# scala map get the value by key with key case insensitive

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have a map of Map[String, Info], it contains keys which can be either uppercase or lowercase, like this:

```
person1: PersonInfo1
person2: PersonInfo2
PERSON1: PersonInfo1
```

i want to get the value for key 'person1', if nothing found I'll try with key of 'PERSON1', I tried this code:

```
val info = map.get(key) match {
  case Some(personInfo) => personInfo
  case None =>
    map.get(key.toUpperCase()) match {
      case Some(personInfo) => personInfo
      case None             => None
    }
}
```

but this return info as type of Product with Serializable, how can I have info returned as type of PersonInfo? Is there a way in Scala that allow me to get value from map by key and ignore cases of the key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are comparators for sorted maps which allow getting from the map case insensitively. Example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PfHTh16CROag7PNrknx1sQ

```
val map = scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap("key1" -> 45, "Key2" -> 43, "KEY3" -> 42)(scala.math.Ordering.comparatorToOrdering(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
map.get("key1") // Some(45)
map.get("key2") // Some(43)
map.get("key3") // Some(42)
map.get("key4") // None
```

Your actual problem can be fixed if you return Options on all cases, for example:

```
      val info = map.get(key) match {
        case somePi@Some(personInfo) => somePi
        case None => map.get(key.toUpperCase()) match {
          case Some(personInfo) => Some(personInfo)
          case None => None
        }
      }
```

Note the `somePi@` `=> somePi` parts for referring the expression or the `Some(personInfo)`.

Probably worth explaining **why** you got this error message. I assume `personInfo` is a `case class` which implements `Product` and `Serializable`, just like `None`. The common type for them is `Product with Serializable`.

Comment: this works, but I would suggest to update your answer with what @Anoukh wrote - his solution uses normal map API without introducing new map types. But great that you present the knowledge about comparators - may be useful in other contexts as well

Comment: @kiedysktos the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156097/1502148 has O(N) time complexity, so I would not recommend that for larger `Map`s. (This solution has O(log(N)) time complexity.) I would prefer not recommending that.

Answer (score 7):

You could chain gets with `orElse`. I would create an extension method for that:

```
implicit class CaseInsensitiveGetMap[V] (m: Map[String,V]) {
   def iget (key: String): Option[V] = m.get(key)
      .orElse(m.get(key.toUpperCase())) //you can add more orElse in chain
}
```

Then you can just use it like:

```
map.iget("person2")
```

Comment: This is a good example for learning implicit classes.

Comment: this is not case insensitive solution - it won't work if you have mixed cases in original map, like `PerSon1`. Solution by @Anoukh does that

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting `Product with Serializable` is because your code is trying to return either a `String` (if key is good) or an `Option` (i.e. `None` if key not found). Those two types are not compatible. You should decide if you want `String` (maybe an empty string if key not found) **or** `Option` (i.e. `Some[String]` or `None`).

See if this works for you. It returns an `Option[String]`.

```
map.get(key).fold(pm.get(key.toUpperCase))(Some(_))
```

The 1st `get()` returns an `Option`. The `fold()()` unwraps the `Option` and either tries a 2nd `get()` with upper case `key` value, or, if the 1st `get` returned a value, the value is re-wrapped in an `Option` so that the types match up.

If, on the other hand, you want to return a `String` instead, you might do this.

```
map.getOrElse(key, pm.getOrElse(key.toUpperCase, ""))
```

Comment: can you explain what this does?

Comment: It does what you attempted to, though it will not work if you have `Key` in your keys and you ask for `key`. In case it is not found, it asks with all uppercase, otherwise it wraps the found value extracted from a `Some` in `Some`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a `find` instead of a `get` but you may want to consider performance when doing this.

```
map.find(k => k._1.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) match {
  case Some =>
  case None =>
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually *answers* the question in the title. Thank you.